# Linq, project elements from 2 lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class:

```
public class Composite
{
    int Width { get; set; }
    int Distance { get; set; }
}
```

And 2 lists:

```
var widths = new List<int>(new[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4 } );
var distances = new List<int>(new[] { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
```

I want to create 5 Composite instances by combining the width and distance using the same index in the source lists:

- 0 & 5
- 1 & 6
- 2 & 7
- 3 & 8
- 4 & 9

I'm guessing some kind of join selecting into the composite but joined by the index of the source lists. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Check the article @ http://techbrij.com/linq-combine-multiple-lists-parallel-c , specially Zip extension.

Comment: That's really useful, thanks. Inevitably these things get more complicated and knowing how to combine more than 2 sources and mixing types is bound to be useful in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var composites = widths.Zip(distances, (w, d) => new Composite() { Width = w, Distance = d })
                       .ToList();
```